# Unable to resolve file-saver.js dependency file from bower install angular-file-saver

Tags: bower-install

I'm using the following command - `bower install angular-file-saver --save` , which has internal dependency on bower file-saver.js#~1.20150507.2. This dependency is not able to download as this is not available at this git url -  [https://github.com/Teleborder/FileSaver.js.git#~1.20150507.2](https://github.com/Teleborder/FileSaver.js.git#%7E1.20150507.2).

It is showing the following error -  `ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/Teleborder/FileSaver.js.git", exit code of #128 fatal`. Clicking on that link gives me a 404 error.

I can use the command `bower install FileSaver --save` and it downloads fine but it won't resolve for the dependency of `bower install angular-file-saver`.

Comment: I have same problem. How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Seems like Teleborder changed their [GitHub](https://github.com/Teleborder) to be private... I'm trying to solve by redirecting bower to a different URL.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same issue,

Due to the aparently abandon of the original repo, I forked and create a new npm package ng-file-saver with the fix.

Basically y updated the FileSaver.js dependency, the rest of the code was no changed

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-file-saver

#### NPM

- `npm i ng-file-saver`

#### BOWER

As Bower is deprecated, registering new Bower packages is not supported anymore. Neverthless you can install any GitHub repository as Bower package by putting full name in bower.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-file-saver": "elquimeras/ng-file-saver#^1.1.4"
  }
}
```

You can install any dependency from github with CLI as well:

`bower install elquimeras/ng-file-saver --save`

Comment: That's great. I solved same problem using this way.

Answer (score 3):

We were able to resolve by using the npm package rather than the bower one:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

1. Remove the file-saver line from the bower.json file
2. Install via npm (or yarn, or pnpm...): `npm install --save file-saver@1.2.0`

Comment: Is there a way to make the change in Tez source code? I couldn't execute the `npm install`.