# angular-file-saver is not installed

Tags: angularjs, bower, bower-install, filesaver.js

Hi All Experts of Angularjs
I am using bower install for my angular project

```
"file-saver.js": "^1.20150507.2",
"angular-file-saver": "^1.1.3",
```

I am getting error when bower install, FileSaver repository not found, I checked it in GitHub, This repository really was gone away.

```
https://github.com/Teleborder/FileSaver.js.git#~1.20150507.2
```

Help me!!! How can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

same problem here. Just make this changes:

Add to your .bowerrc

```
"ignoredDependencies": [
    "file-saver.js"
 ]
```

Then in bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "file-saver": "2.0.4",
   ...
},
"overrides": {
   ...
    "angular-file-saver": {
      "dependencies": {},
      "main": ["dist/angular-file-saver.js"]
    },
    "file-saver": {
      "main": "dist/FileSaver.js"
    },
   ...
}
```

Comment: Updated as above but still facing the same issue.

Comment: @nprakash did you run bower install? If problem persist you can try removing bower_components folder

Comment: This allows my project to build, but I am then left with the error `Module 'ngFileSaver' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.`

Answer (score 1):

[Unable to resolve file-saver.js dependency file from bower install angular-file-saver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71979265/unable-to-resolve-file-saver-js-dependency-file-from-bower-install-angular-file)

This article will solve your problem.

I faced same problem and solved it.